# JavaScript Date time zone confusion

Tags: javascript, datetime, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

Here is my code and my problem is being caused by my browser I think...

```
                    // TODO This will be replaced with an ajax call... testing:  T00:00:00-05:00  T00:00:00.000Z
                    sampleJson = '[{ "MinMonth": "01", "MinYear": "2005", "MaxMonth": "06", "MaxMYear": "2015" }]';
                    var myObject = sampleJson.substring(1, sampleJson.length - 1);
                    myObj = jQuery.parseJSON(myObject);
                    minDate = new Date(myObj.MinYear + "-" + myObj.MinMonth + "-01");
                    console.log(minDate);
                    //console.log(sampleJson);
                    $(".date-picker").datepicker({
                        format: "mm-yyyy",
                        //viewMode: "year",
                        minViewMode: "months",
                        defaultViewDate: "year",
                        startDate: minDate,
                        startView: "years",
                        todayBtn: false,
                        autoclose: true

                    });
                    console.log(minDate);
```

Here's what I get in console.log():
Fri Dec 31 2004 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

Also, on the 5th line down, I've already tried ending "-01"); with "T00:00:00-05:00" to declare(imply) a time zone and it works, but I'm worried it won't work for people outside my (Eastern Standard Time) time zone...

I've tried passing in the date as a string but DatePicker clearly wants a date object since it defaults the value to today's date if I don't use the initializing command "new Date(...)" on the 5th line.  Any help would be very much appreciated, I have researched and found a few related posts but none have helped.

Also, I've tried putting "Z" for the timezone and I thought that would prevent the browser from subtracting the difference in time zone hours but it still did.

UPDATE 7/1/2016:

```
                    // TODO This will be replaced with an ajax call... testing:  T00:00:00-05:00  T00:00:00.000Z
                    sampleJson = '[{ "MinMonth": "01", "MinYear": "2005", "MaxMonth": "06", "MaxMYear": "2015" }]';
                    var myObject = sampleJson.substring(1, sampleJson.length - 1);
                    myObj = jQuery.parseJSON(myObject);
                    minDate = new Date(Date.UTC(myObj.MinYear, (myObj.MinMonth - 1)));
                    console.log(minDate);
                    //console.log(sampleJson);
                    $(".date-picker").datepicker({
                        format: "mm-yyyy",
                        //viewMode: "year",
                        minViewMode: "months",
                        defaultViewDate: "year",
                        startDate: minDate,
                        startView: "years",
                        todayBtn: false,
                        autoclose: true

                    });
                    console.log(minDate);
```

I've tried implementing the UTC function to simply subtract from 1970 or whatever and it still subtracts -5 hours from that date... The browser clearly wants to win this fight...

Comment: I can highly recommend moment.js for all javascript date related issues

Comment: Thanks @ste-fu, I'm going to look into that now.